# Same code and same data run on Tensorflow on Ubuntu (16.04-16.10) or Redhat (7.3) gives very different results

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, redhat, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a Convolutional Neural Network script using tensorflow on the same python version using anaconda distribution (Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)) on the exact same dataset, on 2 different machines:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-     noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.3 (Maipo)
Release:    7.3
```

and

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
```

In both of the machines I have installed tensorflow using `pip install tensorflow` (v0.12) and before doing that I ran a `conda update --all` to make sure I had all the packages with same versions.

Here the fun part starts. Only on the RedHat mahcine the ADAM optimizer converges (I predict the 3d location of neurons and it goes below 10um in around 500 epochs and the final accuracy on validation is around 5um on validation set). Excatly same code and exactly same data (cloned as they are from git) on 
the Ubuntu machine give much worse results: after 500 iteration the error is still around 48 um (starting 'random' accuracy is 69 um) and the final accuracy is around 56um on the validation set.

Now, I checked that the data are exactly the same, they are shuffled with the same random seed and the training and validation set are the same. It only seems that the ADAM optimizer (or others as well) does not converge on the Ubuntu system, while it easily converges on the Redhat one.

This are the first iterations:

RedHat

```
step  0 , training accuracy  81.1025 
step  50 , training accuracy  30.0194 
step  100 , training accuracy  25.263  
step  150 , training accuracy  19.4822 
step  200 , training accuracy  12.0292  
step  250 , training accuracy  8.85796 
step  300 , training accuracy  7.88442  
step  350 , training accuracy  7.20183 
step  400 , training accuracy  7.10236 
step  450 , training accuracy  6.14335  
step  500 , training accuracy  6.20344
```

Ubuntu

```
step  0 , training accuracy  69.9108  
step  50 , training accuracy  57.8822 
step  100 , training accuracy  56.905 
step  150 , training accuracy  54.9463
step  200 , training accuracy  53.7637
step  250 , training accuracy  53.3795
step  300 , training accuracy  50.9828
step  350 , training accuracy  50.4627
step  400 , training accuracy  48.7606
step  450 , training accuracy  47.8309
step  500 , training accuracy  47.8226
```

On the Redhat machine the CNN converges also using other optimizers. I tried the same code and the same data also on another machine with the same Redhat version installed and on Ubuntu 16.04 and I got the same weird results: working properly on Redhat, and not converging on Ubuntu.

I have no idea how the results I get are so different, since I checked that all the installed packages version are the same.

Comment: How are you initialising the weights of the networks. If you are using some kind of a random initialiser are you using some kind of a seed?? Have you tried running the same network twice in the same machine?

Comment: Hi @Kashyap and thank you for replying. I use the tensorflow built-in random seed for the graph `set_random_seed` and also by adding the seed parameter in the `truncated_normal()` function. I'm able to reproduce the good (RedHat) and bad (Ubuntu) results on different machines. I also checked that the variables are initialized with the same values in both operating systems, but as the optimization goes by, they start to get different. I got exactly the same results on 2 different RedHat machines.

Comment: Hi guys, I found the problem and it is something quite simple which might be interesting. It turned out that RedHat automatically loads files in a folder (using `os.listdir()`) in alphabetical order and Ubuntu does not. So the problem was due to the fact that I was loading inputs and outputs in the wrong order in Ubuntu, but in RedHat that was sorted out because the corresponding files are alphabetically ordered. Thank you again!

Comment: The way you read the inputs shouldn't matter for the neural network code. While feeding the input to the neural network code make sure to shuffle the file order and then feed it.